# Is there any way to insert data into a lookup field without an associated relationship sObject until the real data can be inserted?

Tags: lookup, relationships, bulk

How can I programmatically create an object with a lookup field to an object that would be added at a later time? Is it possible? If yes, what is the best way to do it? I would like to use this to create a lookup from an object type to itself. The field might look like:
Account__r = Account__c.ExternalId
and accounts would be added in bulk. The external id would point to an item that is created later. Is this possible with cloning, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a look-up field has to reference a record that is currently in the system. And the salesforce record Ids can't be set by an external system. Inserting the external Id is a good start, but you will need to add a trigger to match up the records after they are inserted to get the look up field populated.

Answer (score 3):

You should better use `Metadata API` for this. You can either handle in Salesforce custom code or by building external applications like in `Java` to work on Metadata components. Refer this link [Metadata Intro](http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/10/27/introduction-to-calling-the-metadata-api-from-apex/).

The `CustomField` metadata type can be used to `create/update/delete` custom field definitions on standard, custom or even external objects or standard field definitions or standard objects. This type extends the metadata type and inherits `fullName` field.
For example a custom field on Standard object has the `fullName` as:

```
Account.MyAcctCustomField__c
```

Comment: I marked the answer above as the right answer, because it would have simplified my solution, but I am sure this is a good answer as well, although I have not implemented it, yet.

Comment: Can you still upvote as this is the solution I'm using in one of my projects. :)

Comment: I don't have enough points, yet. I will as soon as I get them if I don't forget. thanks!

Comment: Upvoted some of your points here ;)